# Convert JSON error result to String in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have a vb.net program that posts a JSON to a Web API and returns a Result.
When the API returns an Error I need to create a Sting of the Error to display in the Program.
I am using Newtonsoft.Json

The Error that is Returned is.
{"message":"One or more input exceptions have occurred.","errors":[{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"name"}},{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"base64_encoded_data"}},{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"type"}}],"trace":"TraceMessageHasBeenDeleted {main}"}

I have Extracted the Message by

```
Dim responseFromAPI As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim rawResponseFromAPI As String
    Dim responseFromAPIStream As Stream
    Dim responseFromAPIReader As StreamReader
    Dim responseFromAPIObject As JObject

    ' Check Result
    If responseFromAPI.IsSuccessStatusCode = False Then
        ' Add Error to Error Collection
        responseFromAPIStream = Await responseFromAPI.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
        responseFromAPIReader = New StreamReader(responseFromAPIStream)
        rawResponseFromAPI = responseFromAPIReader.ReadToEnd()
        responseFromAPIObject = JObject.Parse(rawResponseFromAPI)

        ' Check for Message
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromAPIObject("message").ToString())
        CustomErrorCollection.AddError(responseFromAPIObject("message").ToString())
    End If
```

This returns the Message "One or more input exceptions have occurred."

But I also need to extract all the "Messages" from in the "errors" section and replace the "%fieldName" with the parameter of "fieldName"

So the Final result I am looking for is a Multi line string.
"
One or more input exceptions have occurred.
name is required. Enter and try again.
base64_encoded_data is required. Enter and try again.
type is required. Enter and try again."

There is probably a very simple way to achieve this but after a couple of hours searching and experimenting I haven't got anywhere.

Many Thanks

Comment: You are only returning the `message` property of the object.  Use your debugger to inspect the `responseFromAPIObject` and you should see what else is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

To assist with navigating deserialized Json, it's best to make objects which represent your json properties and derserialize into those.

```
{
   "message":"One or more input exceptions have occurred.",
   "errors":[
      {
         "message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
         "parameters":{
            "fieldName":"name"
         }
      },
      {
         "message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
         "parameters":{
            "fieldName":"base64_encoded_data"
         }
      },
      {
         "message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
         "parameters":{
            "fieldName":"type"
         }
      }
   ],
   "trace":"TraceMessageHasBeenDeleted {main}"
}
```

Looking at your json example, you have three (3) main properties `Message`, `Errors`, and `Trace`. You can define an object that holds these properties and call
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of YourRepresentativeObject)(yourJsonString)`

This would look like:

```vb
Public Class ErrorResponse
    Public Property Message As String
    Public Property Errors As List(Of ErrorDefinition)
    Public Property Trace As String
End Class

Public Class ErrorDefinition
    Public Property Message As String
    Public Property Parameters As Parameter
End Class

Public Class Parameter
    Public Property FieldName As String
End Class
```

And your code to deserialize and utilize would be:

```vb
Dim responseFromAPIObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ErrorResponse)(rawResponseFromAPI)

Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
builder.AppendLine(responseFromAPIObject.Message) 'Get the main message

For Each definition In responseFromAPIObject.Errors 'Get the error definitions
    'replace the placeholder with the parameter fieldName
    builder.AppendLine(definition.Message.Replace("%fieldName", definition.Parameters.FieldName))
Next

Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString)
```

Final Output:

```
One or more input exceptions have occurred.
"name" is required. Enter and try again.
"base64_encoded_data" is required. Enter and try again.
"type" is required. Enter and try again.
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Helps to Understand. How can I get the "fieldName" text from each "error"? i.e. the actual text "fieldName" as the next error may have a parameter of "response" - As {"message":"The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Catalog::categories"}

Comment: Well the current model doesn't account for that. Your Parameters model would need a resources property.